# How to select items for groups of two

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I have a html list:

```
Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 Item 4 Item 5 Item 6
```

I'm trying to add a style only to the elements 3/4, 7/8 ... simulating a grouping with rows of two columns.
For example:

```
Item 1 Item 2 Item 3(add style) Item 4(add style) Item 5 Item 6 Item 7(add style)
```

I'm trying this `:nth-child` but I'm not sure it's possible.
Maybe I could do it in JavaScript in a loop with %?

Comment: What's next iteration: 11/12, or 15/16?

Comment: li:nth-child(4n-1), li:nth-child(4n) {
  //style
}

Comment: **Yess**, @MayurPatil, this works!. Now I just have to study. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
var results = [];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('para');
for (let i = 2; i < elements.length; i++) {
    results.push(elements[i]);
    if(elements[i + 1]) results.push(elements[i + 1]);
    i += 3;
}
Array.from(results, e => {
    e.style.backgroundColor = "gray", e.style.color = 'purple'
});
```

```html
<p class="para">1</p>
<p class="para">2</p>
<p class="para">3</p>
<p class="para">4</p>
<p class="para">5</p>
<p class="para">6</p>
<p class="para">7</p>
<p class="para">8</p>
<p class="para">9</p>
<p class="para">10</p>
<p class="para">11</p>
<p class="para">12</p>
<p class="para">13</p>
<p class="para">14</p>
<p class="para">15</p>
<p class="para">16</p>
<p class="para">17</p>
<p class="para">18</p>
```

same thing can be done using css as per Mayur's comment,

```
<style>    
    p:nth-child(4n-1), p:nth-child(4n) { 
        color:purple;
        background-color: gray;
    } 
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, the javascript solution is very much appreciated. For now I use the css solution

Answer (score 0):

in your css file:

```
li:nth-child(4n-1), nth-child(4n) {
  color:red
}
```

if sass file:

```
li
   &:nth-child(4n-1), &:nth-child(4n)
     color: red
```

if scss file:

```
li {
  &:nth-child(4n-1), &:nth-child(4n) {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Note: best practice is to avoid css manipulation with javascript. if you want to, manipulate the classes to add/remove based on requirements. write css for those classes.